# Finding all words and their frequencies in an elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch Newbie here. I have an elasticsearch cluster and an index http://localhost:9200/products and each product looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "laptop",
  "description" : "Intel Laptop with 16 GB RAM",
  "title" : "...."
}
```

I wanted all keywords in a field and their frequencies across all documents for an index. For eg.

description : intel -> 2500, laptop -> 40000 etc. I looked at termvectors https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html but that only let's me do it across a single document. I want it across all documents in a particular field.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a plug-in for this ..but its expensive call ( based on how many terms you want to get and cardinality of terms ) https://github.com/nirmalc/es-termstat

Comment: This is brilliant. I have not tested it but I'm sure the it would be an expensive call. Also well written code. +1

Comment: Is this a plugin that would have to be installed on elastic search cluster?

Comment: Yes - it needs to be

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way to use term vectors on all documents at a time in an index. You can either use [single](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html) term vector API for single document's term frequency count or [multi-term](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-multi-termvectors.html) vectors API to multiple document's term frequency. But a possible workaround could be like this -

> make a scan request in order to get all documents from a given type,
> and for each page to build a multi-term vector mentioned above to
> request to get term vectors.

```
POST /products/_mtermvectors
{
    "ids" : ["1", "2"],
    "parameters": {
        "fields": [
            "description"
        ],
        "term_statistics": true
    }
}
```